# Find a character in an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying hard to find how to print the position of a character inside an char[20]. Can anyone help me?

```
int emfanisi(char a[])
{
    int i, mikos;
    char b;

    printf("Dose xaraktira\n");
    scanf("%s", b);
    mikos = strlen(a);
    for(i=0; i<mikos; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == b)
            return i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited with what i have tried

Comment: Did your compiler emit any warnings or failures at the line `scanf("%s", b);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to search the character in the string and return the position in the array if it exists in the array.

You should scanf the `character` and not a `string`

change your scanf() like this so that your condition check `if(a[i] == b)` works

```
scanf("%c", &b);
```

And include an error condition when the character is not found in the string.
After for loop return does not happen in the for loop.

```
return -1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if char doesn't match in first iteration, the loop will break. Changes are made below.

On a side note there is already a function to locate a char in a string:  `strchr(str,char)`.

Code:

```
int emfanisi(char a[])
{
    int i, mikos;
    char b;

    printf("Dose xaraktira\n");
    scanf("%c", &b);
    mikos = strlen(a);
    for(i=0; i<mikos; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == b)
            return i;
    }
    return -1; //Indicate doesn't found.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strchr function to do what you desire.

> The strchr() function shall locate the first occurrence of c
>   (converted to a char) in the string pointed to by s. The terminating
>   null byte is considered to be part of the string.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html

if the return value is not null (i.e. character found) you can get the index using:

```
const char* res = strchr(cstr,'A');
int index = cstr-res; //< NOTE: you should check that res != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do what you want:

```
const char * pos = strchr(your_string, character_you_search_for);
if(!pos)
  printf("not found\n");
else
  printf("position is : %d\n", pos - your_string);
```

strchr returns pointer to first occurence of character, so by subtracting your_string from it you get its offset.